# How to make full screen setup wizard in winform?

Tags: winforms, setup-project

Some of application Installation wizard's are in full screen. like below one. This look say "I am a big Program".

[image]

But winform setup installation is like a form only. how can i get like the above installation wizard.

Is possible in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Full screen installers are annoying.  I want to use my computer not look at your ugly ass installer for 5 hours.

Comment: This used to be customary back around the time, say, that Adobe PageMaker 6.5 was released—a very long time ago. There's no reason to do this nowadays because it's not what your users are expecting. I can't think of a possible justification for a full screen, take-over-your-entire-machine installer.

Comment: All are saying this a not a good. Ok. But How to make like this?. If you know tell me pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Installer supports something like this: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/ui-slideshow.html

I don't know if there are other tools which support it, but you can check them out:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Another solution is to write your own custom action which shows the background images.